# What is the relation between solidity and lift coefficients?

Tags: propeller, lift, turbine, theory

I've seen this graph in a couple of places. I'm not sure what it's supposed to mean, as the formulae I've seen in the papers cannot be found in any standard book or reference.

Please let me know if there is some solid reference for this, or if you could explain what exactly this graph represents.

[image: Lift coefficient ratio vs solidity]

Comment: Could you provide a link to a paper that it is from?

Comment: @MikeY One of them: https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/37995514.pdf

Comment: What are *l* and *t* and what are the coefficients that we are getting the ratio of?

Comment: @MikeY t/l is solidity, and I'm not sure about what those coefficients are. One of them is the lift coefficient that we normally use.